# How to disable an input field from typescript file

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is my first angular project. Just started today. I have a form and I want to disable the input field.

This is my `.html` file below:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="projectTitle" class="label">Project Title</label>
    <input type="text" fullWidth id="projectTitle" value= 
    {{projectDetails.name}}" placeholder="Project Title">
</div>
```

How to disable the `input` from the `.ts` file?

Comment: I think he wants to know how to disable it from the typescript file, not only the html. In any case, you just bind `disabled` to a boolean in your ts file and if you want it to be disabled, you just set the boolean that way

Comment: Actually I don't know how to access the element in the html. How can I access that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In HTML add conditional `[disabled]` attribute

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="projectTitle" class="label">Project Title</label>
    <input type="text" fullWidth id="projectTitle" [value]="projectDetails.name" [disabled]="isEnabled" placeholder="Project Title">
</div>
```

Toggle it to `true` or `false` from .ts

```
this.isEnabled = false;
```

If it helped, consider upvoting to the answer, please.

Comment: Thanks Mohd Zeeshan. It helped

Answer (score 0):

Template

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="projectTitle" class="label">Project Title</label>
        <input type="text" [attr.disabled]="isEnabled? '' : null" fullWidth id="projectTitle" value= 
        {{projectDetails.name}}" placeholder="Project Title">
    </div>
```

try component property instead of true to disable conditionally.

```
.ts
isEnabled:boolean = false;
```

Comment: And in the `.ts` file how to change it?

Answer (score -2):

just add `disabled` tag to your input:

```
<input type="text" fullWidth id="projectTitle" value= 
    {{projectDetails.name}}" disabled placeholder="Project Title">
```

in jquery :
disable:

```
$("#projectTitle").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

enable:

```
$("#projectTitle").removeAttr('disabled');
```